# Why TMSI is required when we have IMSI?

Tags: communication, wireless, telecommunications

In several 3gpp documentation pages, it is mentioned that we use TMSI in every sim cards to identify the user in a local network. But my questions is that if we have IMSI, then why they need TMSI for the local geographical area ?

**Note: If this is not the place for questions on 3GPP and mobile application framework, then please mention where I can ask these types of questions**

Comment: when I googled '3gpp TMSI', the third hit started with 'The intention of TMSI is ... '. Google might be a good place to start!

Answer (score 1):

Googling 'TMSI' gave me this answer straight away. Looks like a pretty convincing explanation. The key word here is **privacy**.

> The Temporary Mobile Subscriber Identity (TMSI) is a **temporary**
>   identification number that is used in the GSM network instead of the
>   IMSI to ensure the **privacy** of the mobile subscriber. The TMSI
>   prohibits tracing of the identity of a mobile subscriber by
>   interception of the traffic on the radio link

Comment: So if the IMSI is "always" sent enrypted and TMSI is used instead, then why are we able to get IMSI with this: https://github.com/ptrkrysik/gr-gsm/wiki/Passive-IMSI-Catcher ??

Comment: A possible answer: http://laforge.gnumonks.org/blog/20100628-the_reason_for_paging_by_imsi/